# Custom controls and event handling?

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I have a **windows custom control** with a `picturebox` and a `button` on it's default `panel`. This **windows custom control** will be added to a **windows form**. There is another windows form called `form2`. when the user double clicks on the custom control, it should load `form2`. in designer when i double clicked the custom control on the form, it creates a `load()` event for that custom control. But i need double click event, how this can be done?

[image]

here is the graphical view of what happens
[image]

Here is code in the control

```
    [DefaultEvent("DoubleClick")]
public partial class cntrlImageLoader : UserControl
{
    public cntrlImageLoader()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.InitialDirectory = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures.ToString();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pbImage.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
        }
    }

    private void pbImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.cntrlImageLoader_DoubleClick(pbImage, e);
    }

    private void cntrlImageLoader_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void cntrlImageLoader_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Here is the calling code on form1

```
private void cntrImLdrFront_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //this.cntrImLdrFront.pbImage.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(pbImage_DoubleClick);

}

FrmImageViewer f; // this is form2
private void pbImage_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    f= new FrmImageViewer();
    f.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
    f.Show();
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code. What you want exactly and what it is showing now?

Comment: Create a separate class for `LoadPictureEventArgs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the attribute `[DefaultEvent("DoubleClick")]` at the class declaration.

```
[DefaultEvent("DoubleClick")]
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
}
```

This will creates event which you have set by default on double click of control at design time where you have placed your user control.

**EDITED:**

```
[DefaultEvent("LoadPicture")]
public partial class cntrlImageLoader : UserControl
{
    public delegate void LoadPictureEventHandler(object sender, LoadPictureEventArgs e);
    public event LoadPictureEventHandler LoadPicture;

    private void pbImage_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (LoadPicture != null)
        {
            LoadPictureEventArgs ev = new LoadPictureEventArgs();
            LoadPicture(this, ev);
            if (ev.Picture != null)
            {
                pbImage.Image = ev.Picture;
            }
        }
    }          
}
```

Create another class and give that class name to `LoadPictureEventArgs`

```
public class LoadPictureEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Image Picture {get; set;}
    public LoadPictureEventArgs(Image _picture)
    {
        Picture = _picture
    }
    public LoadPictureEventArgs()
                    : base()
    {
    }
}
```

**HOW TO USE IT?**

```
//FORM1
private void cntrImLdrFron_LoadPicture(object sender, LoadPictureEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = null;
    //LOAD YOUR IMAGE HERE
    e.Picture = img;

}
```

Comment: sorry this does not solve it, i have added the structure of the panel for better understanding

Comment: @PhillGreggan I have updated my answer please take a look. I think you need something like this. I have created an Event that will be called when you double click on the picture box and you can handle it in `Form1`. In that form you can browse the image and assign then picture to that user control.